# How to Change multiple background image sequence on single scroll event by using Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working one project in which I try to change background image sequence on single scroll event in Vanilla JavaScript.

I already try some method to change the background image sequence on scrolling event but the image change in individual scrolling scrub like one scroll scrub change one image. It's not my expected result. I'm try to change multiple image in single scrolling scrub. Here is the reference of one project which I try to clone for study purpose.  https://www.echostreetcapital.com

Comment: Do you mean you want it to show an animation when scrolled between images?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replay but Not kind of as you say! I want to get output like when we do a single scrub of mouse scroll and the entire 100Vh set section will be sifted up and the next section will appear, that single section shifting duration I want to change the multi-image in sequence in single mouse scroll scrub. for desired results output check out this webpage https://www.echostreetcapital.com